# cURL POST Request from Rails-API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl

I'm using the rails-api gem and trying to use curl to POST some data to the API (to populate the Campaigns entity). This model only has one attribute name.

My curl request:

```
curl -d "name=Facebook" http://localhost:3000/campaigns/
```

The name attribute ends up being null looking at the json response.
I then changed it to this:

```
curl -d "campaign[name]=Facebook" http://localhost:3000/campaigns/
```

This just seems to render some HTML in the terminal. Looking at the HTML there is a message on the lines of **forbidden_attributes_protection**.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding in your

```
params.require(:compaign).permit(:name)
```

This looks like a strong parameters error. http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html

Comment: Oh yes of course. I am familiar with Strong Params from my other Rails projects but I hadn't considered them for the rails-api. I will check it out and get back to you.